# package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist

Tags: java, servlets

I have some of the following imports defined like the following as shown in the image below.

[image]

I am wondering, how can I eliminate `"package javax.servlet.annotation does not exist"` error. I am currently working on "Java Web" type of project in Netbeans 7.4. .

Secondly, I believe , the above error is the reason behind my second error related to "WebServlet" which is shown in the image above (line #44).

Please let me know how to fix this problem.

Read some other posts [like this one](http://www.coderanch.com/t/550030/Servlets/java/package-javax-servlet-annotation-exist), but I believe they are not using Netbeans and not sure if I should update tomcat as mentioned in the post. The location of the servlet api jar file is as shown in the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`WebServlet` is added in `servlet-api` version 3.0, so make sure you are using updated version and it's added in the class path of the project.

Have a look at [servlet-api-2.5 classes](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapi25jar.htm) where `WebServlet.class` is not included, it's part of [servlet-api-3.x classes](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapijar.htm)

Comment: If `servlet-api` was not there, then I would have been getting errors on other servlet related imports as well related to servlet but I am not as evident from the above image. Why am I getting this error in the context of annotation only?

Comment: clean the project because some time IDE behave in this way.

Comment: I ran `Clean and Build` but still encountering same errors.The `Read more` link you shared is talking about `pom.xml`. I don't have any such file. I just have `content.xml` inside `META-INF` folder and `web.xml` inside `WEB-INF` folder. Also, the post you shared is talking about Eclipse and not making much sense as I am using Netbeans 7.4.

Comment: BTW I had in `web.xml` the version number as 2.5 so I changed it to 3.0.

Comment: `pom.xml` is used in MAVAN project only. Try with updated version. what version of `servlet-api` jar do you have?

Comment: In the `servlet-api-jar-->META-INF-->MANIFEST.MF` file, I see `Implementation-Version: 2.5.MR2`. I downloaded, `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar` from here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.servlet|javax.servlet-api|3.0.1|jar  
Should I delete the current `servlet-api jar` and put the one I just downloaded ? P.S: I just updated my question with an additional image.

Comment: Actually, there is no `delete` option when I right click on `servlet-api.jar` which is inside `Apache Tomcat` as shown in the image in my question. Also, when I tried to add the jar file in the `Libraries` folder, it is getting added directly below `Libraries` folder. Is there a way I can add it inside `apache tomcat` or should I leave it as it is(that is inside the `Librarries` folder?

Comment: Is tomcat added in IDE itself? I wish I could but Sorry I haven't worked on Netbeans.

Comment: Have a look at the updated post where you will find the reason of this issue.

Comment: Yeah, in the Services section I see `Apache Tomcat` added in there. So, I went to that folder (Apache Tomcat) and manually deleted the old JAR file and pasted the newly downloaded file. The error disappeared. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank for your cooperation and pointing me to the right direction :)

Answer (score 13):

Solution: Add Java EE Web API Library.

1. In the project window, right-click <libraries>. Then click <Add Library>. then choose <Java EE Web API Library>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tomcat 10 change the import statement from :`javax.servlet.----- to import jakarta.servlet.------.